# Is It Possible to Have a Constraint Annotation That Targets an Interface Instead of a Type?

Tags: java

Is it possible to create a constraint annotation, that targets an interface but can be used to validate any concrete implementation that implements said interface?

For example, we have interface `Identifiable`:

```
public interface Identifiable {
    String getId();
}
```

I'd like to create a constraint, that targets `List<Identifiable>`:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = IdentifiablesValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface Identifiables {
    // ...Constraint properties...
}

public class IdentifiablesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Identifiables, List<Identifiable>> {
    // ...Validator logic...
}
```

And then apply the constraint to a target that implements the interface:

```
public class SomeExampleCase {
   @Identifiables()
   List<IdentifiableImpl> sut;
}
```

But at runtime this results in an error:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'com.example.Identifiables' validating type 'java.util.List<com.example.IdentifiableImpl>'. Check configuration for 'identifiables'
```

The constraint does work for validation, when applied to a list of the interface (e.g. `List<Identifiable>`). But this forces the target class (e.g. `SomeExampleCase`) to use the interface, rather than an implementation - which gets in the way of all types of things (e.g. Marshalling/Unmarshalling).

Is there a way to get the validator to work with an actual `List<Identifiable>`, without rewriting it to target `List?

Thanks in advance!

Update 1: The same issue occurs when the interface is turned into an abstract class.

Answer (score 2):

I came here with the same question and after some trials I got this working for me:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = IdentifiablesValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface Identifiables {
    // ...Constraint properties...
}

public class IdentifiablesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Identifiables, List<? extends Identifiable>> {
    // ...Validator logic...
}
```

The important part is the change of `<? extends Interface>`.